# How do I check what ES version will be required by a browser?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5, transpiler

I have a JS application that is bundled using webpack.  It is mostly VueJs, with some jQuery and raw JS.  It calls in a number of libraries and uses some ES6 features.

I think webpack is transpiling down to ES5, but I am not 100% sure.  I would like to be able to check the output JS, to find out if it is definitely ES5 or lower. How can I do that?

I tried this node module, https://www.npmjs.com/package/es-check, but could not get any sense out of it.  It keeps saying that it can't find any files to check.

Comment: Try checking the output for ES2015 features?

Comment: How do I do that?  I can't eyeball it - there's too much.

Comment: One way to search for `=>`. It’s not foolproof, but it’s a start. Otherwise just check your build tool.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to use `grep` or similar on the bundle and search for any of these:

```
cat bundle.js | grep =\>
```

- arrow function `=\>`
- declarations `let\` `const\`